# Messenger.SendToTargetOrType and messageType key

Tags: mvvm-light

Lets say that I want to Send/Register messages of type Exception with a specific token.

```
Messenger.Default.Register(recipient, MessageType.RaiseException, action);
...
Messenger.Default.Send<Exception>(ex, MessageType.RaiseException);
```

If ex is Exception type, and I receive a derived exception (for example InvalidOperationException), then message will never be delivered, since

```
if (_recipientsStrictAction.ContainsKey(messageType))
```

will always return false. Am I wrongly using Messenger, or this is a bug? Should

```
Type messageType = message.GetType();
```

be

```
Type messageType = typeof(TMessage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `receiveDerivedMessages` too to inicate to the messenger that you are not only interested in the specific message type, but in all message types that derive from it.

The actual overload for Register to use is :

```
Register<TMessage>(
    object recipient, 
    object token, 
    bool receiveDerivedMessagesToo, 
    Action<TMessage> action
)
```

So your registration should look like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register(recipient, MessageType.RaiseException, true, action);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that one.